# How to do concrete calculations in algebraic geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, classical-algebraic-geometry

I'm working through Shafarevich's *Basic Algebraic Geometry,* (the first edition, with all three parts in one book), and although I've been able to deal with the conceptual problems or those proving certain varieties are (not) isomorphic/birational, I've run into three specific kinds of calculations that I struggle with.

The first is question 3 of section 2, asking if the ideal of the set defined by the equations $f:x^2+y^2=1$ and $g:x=1$ is simply $(f,g).$ I tried to approach this problem using the fact that each component is irreducible and basically trying to treat the problem like a problem with single-variable polynomials, but I don't think that certain arguments I used carry over from the single variable case to the general case.

The second is question 1 of section 3: decomposing the closed set defined by the equations $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $x^2-y^2-z^2+1=0$ into irreducible components. Quite frankly, I had no idea how to approach this problem, not even a vague inkling. I'd love to factor the ideal generated by the two polynomials, but I don't actually know how to do that either.

The final problem I had, that I think I actually solved, was question 6 of section 3: finding at which points of the circle the function $1-y/x$ was regular. I used the parametrization of the circle to actually turn it into a one dimensional problem, whence I was able to solve it. However, is there a way to solve it in the general case, like for a non-parametrizable curve?

If anyone has any books or resources focusing on calculations in algebraic geometry, that would also be greatly appreciated!

Comment: which is the base field, or is the base field supposed to be algebraically closed?

Comment: what are you seeking as an answer to your third question?

Comment: [This book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-16721-3) is a fairly common reference for computational tools in algebraic geometry and commutative algebra. Once you're comfortable with (or accept) the theory in there, computer languages like [Macaulay2](https://www.unimelb-macaulay2.cloud.edu.au/#home) are really convenient for working these examples out in practice.

Comment: @Federico The base field is always assumed to be algebraically closed, of characteristic not doviding any of the degrees in the polynomial.

Comment: @K02 I was wondering how one could prove that a function is or isn't regular if they didn't already have a rational parameterization on hand.

Comment: @littleman I'm afraid your question is like many questions of this sort. In principle if you know the variety you are on well enough, and the function well enough, then it should be feasible to do so. Afterall, you're just checking that locally the function is a polynomial.

Comment: @hm2020 I've been working through Shafarevich (as mentioned in my question) to prepare/build up to Hartshorne. Are you saying it'd be worth starting off right away with Hartshorne instead? Or that I should do the first chapter's problems while still learning from Shafarevich before trying to get through the rest of Hartshorne?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let me give you some broad resources for doing these kinds of computations. Most of them come down to doing manipulations on ideals, and unfortunately that's not a skill that you usually learn in either a first algebra class *or* in a first algebraic geometry class! So you kind of have to pick it up on your own. I'll also say that there's very little glory in learning to do all this stuff by hand. It's useful, of course, but just like you would never row reduce a matrix by hand (we have computers for that) you should *also* make good use of computers to solve problems like these (though, like row reduction, it's still important to know how these algorithms work)! Depending on where you are in your mathematical career, this may feel like cheating. But I assure you it isn't, haha.

I recommend Schenck's *Computational Algebraic Geometry* as a book that spends a lot of time working out examples in detail. Also Cox, Little, and O'Shea's *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms* is a more comprehensive guide to the computational techniques you can use to solve these kinds of problems. I recommend [Sage](https://sagemath.org) and [Macaulay2](https://macaulay2.com/) as resources for getting a computer to solve your problems for you.

Now, let's look at your specific questions:

---

The ideal of the set defined by $f = x^2 + y^2 - 1$ and $g = x-1$ is, of course, the radical $\sqrt{\langle f, g \rangle}$ (do you see why?). So asking if this is equal to $I = \langle f, g \rangle$ as asking whether $I$ is already radical.

Now, we could just hack away at this. Indeed Macaulay2 says:

```
i1: R = QQ[x,y];
i2: I = ideal (x^2 + y^2 - 1, x-1);
o2: Ideal of R
i3: I == (radical I)
o3 = false
```

but it would be nice to have some geometric intuition for this. We know $f$ defines the unit circle, and $g$ defines the line $x=1$, so the ideal $\langle f, g \rangle$ defines the intersection of these curves. This intersection is of multiplicity $2$ (since a small perturbation of $g$, say to $x=.9$, intersects the unit circle twice), so the intersection is "the point $(1,0)$, twice". Eventually you'll learn that these high-multiplicity intersections correspond to non-reduced schemes (in fact, maybe now is the time to internalize that. It's one of the big reasons to care about schemes over varieties), so we expect this ideal to not be reduced.

Following up on this geometric intuition, we know this intersection is the point $(1,0)$, whose corresponding ideal is $\langle x-1, y \rangle$ (do you see why?). So we learn that $\sqrt{I} = \langle x-1, y \rangle$. Let's check if this is actually equal to $I$! It's not hard to convince yourself that $y \not \in I$, so $I \neq \sqrt{I}$. After going through this process, you'll likely notice that $y^2 \in I$ but $y \not \in I$ gives a faster (purely algebraic) proof that $I \neq \sqrt{I}$.

---

For your second question, we want to find the irreducible components of the set defined by $\langle f, g \rangle$ where now $f = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1$ and $g = x^2 - y^2 - z^2 + 1$.

Now we set $I = \sqrt{ \langle f, g \rangle }$, and we "recall" an important fact: Every radical ideal is the intersection of prime ideals. Writing a radical as the intersection of primes amounts to finding the [associated primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_decomposition#Geometric_interpretation). Again, we can hack away with Macaulay2:

```
i1: R = QQ[x,y,z];
i2: I = ideal (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1, x^2 - y^2 - z^2 + 1);
o2: Ideal of R
i3: associatedPrimes I
o3 = {ideal (x, y^2 + z^2 - 1)}
o3: List
```

So we see that there's exactly one irreducible component of the intersection! Again, it would be nice to leverage our geometric intuition for this one, so what's the plan? Well, these are simple enough 3d shapes that you might already be able to visualize their solution sets over $\mathbb{R}$. If not, a computer can *definitely* help with that! Let's plot these surfaces in contrasting colors, and make the outer surface slightly transparent. We can easily do this in sage with code like

```
implicit_plot3d(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, (x,-1.5,1.5), (y,-1.5,1.5), (z,-1.5,1.5), color="blue") + implicit_plot3d(x^2 - y^2 - z^2 == -1, (x,-1.5,1.5), (y,-1.5,1.5), (z,-1.5,1.5), color="orange", opacity=0.5)
```

this creates an interactive 3d graphic of these surfaces. Here's a screenshot:

[image: a plot of the two surfaces in R^3]

Playing around with the full interaction makes it believable that the intersection should be a single circle. The sphere seems to sit *perfectly* inside the hyperboloid. Again, once you have this geometric picture in mind, the algebraic idea becomes clear: eliminating $x$ from $f$ and $g$ gives

$$
1 - y^2 - z^2 = x^2 = y^2 + z^2 - 1
$$

this rearranges to $y^2 + z^2 = 1$, and back substituting we see this can only happen when $x=0$. We recognize the curve $x=0, \ y^2 + z^2 = 1$ as irreducible, so this is our only component! It's given by the ideal $\langle x, y^2 + z^2 - 1 \rangle$, which agrees with Macaulay2's answer.

---

For your last question, how can we find the points where some rational function is regular?

For an irreducible affine variety $X$ this is fairly easy to answer. The ring of functions $k[X]$ is an integral domain (do you see why?) so that its field of fractions is defined. This field of fractions $k(X)$ is exactly the field of rational functions on $X$, so that every rational function looks like $\frac{f}{g}$ for $f,g \in k[X]$! Even more explicitly, this means that rational functions on $X$ are quotients of polynomials $\frac{f}{g}$ where we say that $\frac{f_1}{g_1} = \frac{f_2}{g_2}$ whenever $f_1 g_2 - f_2 g_1 \in I(X)$.

Now a rational function is undefined exactly when the denominator vanishes! For your example of $1 - \frac{y}{x}$, this is defined whenever $x \neq 0$. That is, everywhere but the two points $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$.

There are some minor subtleties here, familiar from a calculus class. For instance, the rational function $\frac{x^2y}{x}$ is actually regular everywhere, even though it looks like it shouldn't be defined at $x=0$. This is really an artifact of a bad choice of representative, since we could have taken $xy$ instead. In case you're working with more general varieties (or worse: schemes) there are even more subtleties to be aware of, but that's probably left to an answer from someone more experienced.

---

Hopefully this answer conveys the idea that doing the algebra for algebraic geometry becomes easier if you focus harder on the geometry. Hopefully it *also* conveys that despite this, you can sidestep the geometry and just do hard algebra, if push comes to shove. Indeed, this is the whole beauty of the subject -- the algebra is the same, whether you can picture the geometry or not! That said, if there *isn't* any underlying geometry to leverage, the algebraic computations can often be brutal, so they're best left to a computer program like Macaulay2. I highly recommend spending some time getting to know it!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Honestly, I'd heard of both programs you mentioned but I always saw them as esoteric magic powers that only professional mathematicians could understand (and also what you mentioned about it feeling like cheating), but your answer definitely made them feel more concrete, especially when you justified your answers with geometric intuition. Your comment definitely helped, and I'll probably stop insisting on doing all my calculations by hand from now on!

Comment: I'm glad! One of the books I mentioned (Schenck's _Computational Algebraic Geometry_) really reads like a textbook, with lots of examples and exercises, and pictures to help explain the geometry. It just happens to be a textbook which also includes examples and exercises relating to Macaulay2! I would definitely give it a read, since it's a great book for learning algebraic geometry at the same time as learning how to use these tools ^_^

Comment: For the third question, the affine irreducible case is enough to succeed in the general computation (afaik) since you can check regularity locally! Doing checks in the case of a projective variety is more or less along those lines too (take an affine chart, then deal with that case locally, and then check each chart). In any case, this is an excellent answer!

Answer (score 0):

For the first, I would think that if $x^2+y^2=1$ and $x=1$ then $y^2 = 0$ so $y=0$ if we're working over a field, hence $I(V(I)) = \left< y, x-1\right>$.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "If anyone has any books or resources focusing on calculations in algebraic geometry, that would also be greatly appreciated!"

**Comment:** This is more a general comment on how to study algebraic geometry and what to focus on when you are a student. Hartshornes classical book - CH I on "classical algebraic varieties - has many good exercises that are instructive. You should do these exercises.

**Comment:** @hm2020 I've been working through Shafarevich (as mentioned in my question) to prepare/build up to Hartshorne. Are you saying it'd be worth starting off right away with Hartshorne instead? Or that I should do the first chapter's problems while still learning from Shafarevich before trying to get through the rest of Hartshorne?

@littleman - the first chapter in Hartshorne can be read with some knowledge on commutative algebra (you should have read Atiyah-Macdonald or Matsumuras book). My suggestion is to try to do the exercises in HH-CHI - The chapter is in some sense "self contained" and with some work and knowledge on commutative algebra you can fill in all details. I also want to recommend the book of Fulton on algebraic curves. This is also "self contained". It is important to have understood what an algebraic variety is before you try to understand what a scheme is.

In HH-CHI Hartshorne does not speak of sheaves of functions, but when introducing the notion "regular function" and "morphism between varieties" he indirectly defines the structure sheaf of an algebraic variety. He does not formally define the structure sheaf of a classical algebraic variety, but you can try to do this yourself - this is a good exercise. If $Y$ is an algebraic variety in CHI sense and if $U$ is an open subset of $Y$, define the ring $\mathcal{O}_Y(U)$ using the notion "regular function" and prove this is a sheaf of rings on $Y$.

Students struggle understanding the notion "scheme" because the sheaf of rings $\mathcal{O}_X$ on a scheme $X$ is not a "sheaf of functions" in the classical sense. On a general scheme $X$ there is no field $k$ where the ring $A_U$:=$\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ may be considered as a sub ring of the ring of fuctions $M_U:=Map(U,k)$ from U to k. The ring $A_U$ has nilpotent elements and the ring $M_U$ is reduced.

If $X:=Spec(A)$ is an affine scheme and if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a point (correspoinding to a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$) there is a canonical map

$$f_{\mathfrak{p}}: A \rightarrow \kappa(\mathfrak{p})$$

where $\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$ is the residue field. Given a global section $a\in A \cong \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ you may "evaluate" $a$ at $\mathfrak{p}$: The "value" of $a$ at $\mathfrak{p}$ is the element $f_{\mathfrak{p}}(a) \in \kappa(\mathfrak{p})$. What is "unintuitive" is that the residuefield $\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$ varies with the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$. Hence there is "no fixed field $k$" where $a$ may be viewed as a function $a:X \rightarrow k$. If you want to understand this, you must first understand what a sheaf is in the "classical sense".

As an example: If $k$ is the field of real numbers and if $A:=k[x]$, it follows for any element $a\in k$ the ideal $(x-a)$ is a maximal ideal with residue field $k$. The ideal $(x^2+1)$ is a maximal ideal with residue field $\mathbb{C}$.